# Minesweeper program terminates as soon as I run it

Tags: java, terminate, minesweeper

```
    import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class field {
    private int[][] mines;
    private char[][]game;
    private int Row, Column;
    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

//create field array
public field (){
    mines = new int[10][10];
    game = new char [10][10];
    startMines();
    randomMines();
    fillNum();
    startField();
}
//set win conditions
public boolean win(){
    int count=0;
    for(int Row = 1; Row<9; Row++)
        for(int column = 1; column<9; column++)
            if(game[Row][column]=='_')
                count++;
    //if 10 mines are found you win
    if(count==10)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public void openNeighbors(){
    for(int i=-1;i<2;i++)
        for(int j=-1;j<2;j++)
            if((mines[Row+i][Column+j] != -1) && (Row !=0 && Column != 0 && Column !=9))
                game[Row+i][Column+j]=Character.forDigit(mines[Row+i][Column+j], 10);
}
//get the suspected mines position
public int getPosition(int Row, int Column){
    return mines[Row][Column];
}
//have the user input the position of the suspected mine
public boolean setPosition(){

    do{
        System.out.print("\nRow: ");
        Row = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Column: ");
        Column = keyboard.nextInt();

        if( (game[Row][Column] != '_')&&((Row < 9 && Row > 0) && (Column< 9 && Column >0)))
            System.out.println("Field already shown");

        if(Row < 1 || Row >8 || Column < 1 || Column>8)
            System.out.println("Chose a number between 1 and 8.");

    }while((Row <1 || Row>8 || Column<1 || Column>8 || (game[Row][Column] != '_')));

    if(getPosition(Row, Column)==-1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
//show the mine field
public void show(){
    System.out.println("\n    Rows");
    for(int Row = 8; Row>0;Row++){
        System.out.print("     "+Row+" ");

        for(int Column=1; Column<9;Column++){
            System.out.print("   "+game[Row][Column]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    System.out.println("\n            1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8");
    System.out.println("                    Columns");

}
//show the hints for the game when selected
public void fillNum(){
    for(int row=1; row<9;row++)
        for(int column=1; column<9; column++){

            for(int i=-1;i<=1;i++)
                for(int j=-1;j<=1;j++)
                    if(mines[row][column]!=-1)
                        if(mines[row+i][column+j]==-1)
                            mines[row][column]++;


        }
}
//show the mines on the mine field
public void showMines(){
    for(int i=1; i<9;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<9;j++)
            if(mines[i][j]==-1)
                game[i][j]='*';

    show();

}
//generate the field
public void startField(){
    for(int i=1; i<mines.length; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<mines.length; j++)
            game[i][j]='_';

}
//start the mines
public void startMines(){
    for(int i=0; i<mines.length ; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<mines.length; j++)
            mines[i][j]=0;

}
//randomly place the 10 mines
public void randomMines(){
    boolean raffled;
    int Row, Column;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        do{
            Row = random.nextInt(8) +1;
        Column = random.nextInt(8) +1;
        if(mines[Row][Column]==-1)
            raffled=true;
            else
                raffled=false;

        }while(raffled);
        mines[Row][Column]=-1;
    }
}
}
```

Mine Field code

```
 public class Play {
    boolean end = false;
    boolean win = false;
    private field field;
    int turn=0;

    public void Begin(){
        field = new field();
        Start(field);
    }
    public void Start(field field){
        do{
            turn++;
            System.out.println("Turn " +turn);
            field.show();
            end = field.setPosition();

            if(!end){
                field.openNeighbors();
                end = field.win();
            }

        }while(!end);
        if(field.win()){
            System.out.println("You found all 10 of the hidden mines in the minefield in " +turn +"turns.");
        field.showMines();
        }else{
            System.out.println("You hit a mine. You lose.");
        field.showMines();
        }
    }
    }
```

Play the game code

These are my programs for creating the mine field and playing the game. When I compile and run the code the program terminates immediately and doesn't show anything else in the console. The code doesn't appear to have any compiling errors. Any help anyone can provide in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned yet about the Java [`main` method](https://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html)?

Comment: How are you trying to run this? No ide that i know wont give a main method not foound error.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args){new Play().Begin();}`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Play class so that the beginning looks like this:

```
public class Play {
boolean end = false;
boolean win = false;
private field field;
int turn=0;

// All Java programs require  the following method to run, it must
// be declared public, static, void, named "main" and take a 
// String array as an argument.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  Because main must be static (defined at compile time, once per class)
    // you need to create an instance of your play class before you can
    // call Begin()
    new Play().Begin();
}

public void Begin(){
    field = new field();
    Start(field);
}
```

**Note**: By Java convention, method names begin with lower case so Begin() should be begin() and class names begin with capitals, so field should be Field (and Field.java).  Variable names are usually lower case as well.  Not required, but it makes code easier to read in the long run.

Once you've added your main method.  There is also an error in your "show" for loop.  I think you want to decrement Row instead of increment row, based on how your loop is set up.

```
//show the mine field
public void show(){
    System.out.println("\n    Rows");
    for(int Row = 8; Row>0;Row++){ // <-- Try Row-- here instead.
```

Happy programming!

Comment: Thank you for your help the program is up and running perfectly now.

Comment: @hhayes96 I'm happy that was helpful!  Would you mind marking the answer as correct?